# Copy part of a string directly to vector error: no match operator=

Tags: c++, stl, operators

I want to implement a simple function that will split `std::string` based on the delimiter `,\s`.

For example, `split("Emerson, Lake, Palmer")` should yield `std::vector<std::string>` of

```
Emerson
Lake
Palmer
```

I discovered, that it could be simply achieved with [`back_inserter()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_inserter/) (the example is very helpful) . The function below iterates over supplied string and copies its content directly to a vector.

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& s) {
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;

    std::string::const_iterator from = s.begin();
    for (std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin(); it < s.end(); it++) {
        if ( *it == ',' ) {
            std::copy(from, it, std::back_inserter(tokens));
            from = it + 2;
        }
        if (it == s.end()-1)
            std::copy(from, it+1, std::back_inserter(tokens));
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

However, the code doesn't compile with the error

> `no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >' and 'const char')`

I roughly understand what does it mean, however, I don't know how to go about this. Am I missing something simple to make it work, or the whole concept is not a way to go?

Comment: `tokens` is a `vector<string>` so you can add strings: `tokens.emplace_back(std::string(from, it));`

Comment: This isn't a good use of `back_inserter`. Pair `back_inserter` with a function from <algorithm> that eats the input stream as an iterator and stores into a container iterator.

Comment: @Johny's answer gets the job done, however, I am curious what's wrong with this approach. @user4581301, I thought `std::copy` is such a function.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp passing temporary to `emplace_back()` defeats whole purpose of such functions. you basically make it the same as `push_back()`

Comment: @Maverick yes `std::copy()` such a function but to use it here you need to iterate over something that has `std::sting` inside ie `*it` for iterator provides string, not individual symbol.

Comment: You know, you've got me there, @Maverick. I was looking at the question wrong. I knew you were using `std::copy` to gather characters into a string and that the back inserter was expecting a `string`, but the disjoint types totally <expletive deleted>ed up my brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit a range as 2 iterators to `std::copy()` you mean that you want to copy each element that such iterators point to to the target. But `std::string::iterator` points to individual chars and I do not think you want to copy each symbol into the vector separately. Instead you can create a `std::string` from pair and submit it to the vector:

```
for (std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin(); it < s.end(); it++) {
    if ( *it == ',' ) {
        tokens.emplace_back( from, it );
        from = it + 2;
    }
...
```

Comment: Isn't it the approach you criticized in the comments under the question? ;> Nevertheless, maybe there is just nothing better when one wants to stick to my initial idea. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What approach do you mean that I criticized? Please elaborate.

Comment: that passing temporary to emplace_back() defeats the whole purpose of such functions.

Comment: If you look carefully you will see the difference and you should notice that I do not pass temporary of `std::string` but submit 2 iterators directly. That the whole purpose of `emplace...` functions - they forward arguments to ctor. You can find details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50740699/copy-elision-when-creating-object-inside-emplace

Comment: Indeed, I overlooked that one. All is clear now. Have a good day

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
std::copy(from, it, std::back_inserter(tokens));
```

the iterator from supplies objects of the type char while the iterator of the type `std::back_inserter` expects an object of the type `std::string`.

Instead you could write at least

```
tokens.push_back( std::string( from, it ) );
```

or

```
tokens.push_back( { from, it } );
```